# PHP Decode of Google Geocode API JSON Breaks When Response Contains "/"

Tags: php, geocoding, json, google-geocoder

Below is the relevant code in my application.....

```
<?
$jsonData   = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($jsonData, TRUE);
        $lat = $data['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $lng = $data['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        $formattedAddress = $data['results']['0']['formatted_address'];
        $acomp = $data['results']['0']['address_components'];
        foreach ($acomp as $acompArray) {
            if (in_array("neighborhood", $acompArray["types"])) {
                $neighborhood = $acompArray["long_name"];
            }
        }
$acomp = $data['results']['0']['address_components'];
foreach ($acomp as $acompArray) {
    if (in_array("neighborhood", $acompArray["types"])) {
         $neighborhood = $acompArray["long_name"];
    }
}
?>
```

Below is the JSON Response From Google's Geocoder API (one of the examples that broke)

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "3900",
               "short_name" : "3900",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
           "long_name" : "Winchell Avenue",
           "short_name" : "Winchell Ave",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Oakland/Winchell",
           "short_name" : "Oakland/Winchell",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kalamazoo",
           "short_name" : "Kalamazoo",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kalamazoo",
           "short_name" : "Kalamazoo",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Michigan",
           "short_name" : "MI",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "49008",
           "short_name" : "49008",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     ---A LOT MORE BUT DELETED THE IRRELEVANT PORTIONS---
}
```

The problem appears to happen with the neighborhood 'Oakland/Winchell', my theory is that it contains a '/' which appears to make it return nothing... How do i fix this?

Comment: The `/` ought to be escaped. PHPs json_decode however has typically no problems with either. `print_r()` whatever you've got.

Answer (score -1):

```
$json_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$row2[lat].",".$row2[lng]."&sensor=true";
// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results                                                                     
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

// parse the json response
    $jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
    $results = $jsondata['results'][0];
    $addr =$results['formatted_address'];
```

Comment: The code above will allow you to get to the first 'formatted_address' field which has the full description of the address...